# Generating UML class diagrams from Grails domain model

Tags: grails, plugins, tool-uml

Is there a tools or plugin which generates UML class Diagram from grails domain Model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a grails plugin :

http://www.grails.org/plugin/create-domain-uml .

Install it via the following command :

```
grails install-plugin create-domain-uml
```

To run the plugin:

```
grails create-domain-uml
```

This will create a file DomainUML.html in your project root which contains the diagrams.

you can see also : 
http://www.svenlange.co.za/2010/01/generating-uml-class-diagrams-from-grails-domain-model/

Comment: It do not work for grails3 or grails4. I can not run install-plugin command in grails3/4. The see also link is broken.

Comment: This was about grails 2. For grails 3/4, it needs test

Comment: @BobYang the question is from 2013... can't expect that to work today.

Comment: Yeah! longtime almost 10 years .. But give a try & good luck

Answer (score 4):

If you have option to use Intellij IDEA, you can just view the UML from 'Domain Class Dependencies' bottom tab for any domain class opened in editor.